# Is it possible to reduce the need of 20 rep for chat? I need it for making a chat for my classmates.

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, chat, privileges

I'm trying to create a chat room with LaTeX for my classmates, It is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13862/ufpe-bacharelado-de-matematica-2014-1). Is it possible to reduce the need for 20rep for them? They speak only portuguese and won't be able to make a question. But I think that having a chat room with them is going to be a good thing for the class. I wouldn't even mind if I could transfer the reputation from my account to theirs, but I don't know how to do that.

They won't be annoying other users in other chat rooms nor doing annoying questions. I just need a room with LaTeX and loging, so that we can comunicate better. I've tried MathIM, but it does not log the chat.

Comment: You could use web IRC + your own room on a server + the ChatJax bookmark + a program to log everything. (The last part would require technical knowledge though.)

Comment: While it definitely makes sense in your case, I think the devs are unlikely to change the privilege system for what seems like a fairly narrow issue (i.e. affecting only a small number of low-rep users).

Comment: @anon This would be too hard to them (and perhaps hard for me, to configure everything). It's sad, but teaching them how to use such a tool would take a lot of time and demotivation would arise - people in the class come from different backgrounds, some of them don't know so much about using computers. I guess it's way easier through here.

Comment: @AlexBecker I could talk to them, I guess.

Comment: @Pristine No, it would require them going to a website and typing a few things in boxes (server, #math, name) and clicking submit, which is not hard at all. Managing the room (your part) would be the hard part.

Comment: @PristineKavalostka You've already made the feature request--the devs should see it, and will either implement it or decline. I'm just guessing that they'll decline.

Comment: @AlexBecker Just for curiosity: Do you point this link to them or they see everything in all metas?

Comment: @PristineKavalostka They check up on the metas fairly regularly.

Comment: @anon I'll check for that.

Comment: @AlexBecker Ok. Thanks.

Comment: @PristineKavalostka Why not using some of other freely available solutions for chat instead, several are mentioned in [this question on main](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering).

Comment: Similar feature request (but for entirely different reasons) has been made before: [Allow inviting people with rep < 20 to private chat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111942/allow-inviting-people-with-rep-20-to-private-chat).

Answer (score 14):

I imagine that it's actually a deliberate design decision to prevent people who won't use the Q&A function of the site from being able to use the stackexchange network as a chat server.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Our chat is not meant as a general-purpose chat platform, but as a supplement for the existing communities on the main Q&A sites.